# Glassfish: How to know which machine in a cluster is processing a request

Tags: glassfish, ejb, cluster-computing

I'm using Glassfish clustering with 4 machines.

I'm also using remote EJB in order to call a method to this cluster. When I'm calling the method, one of these four machines processes it. I would like to know which one.
So I create a remote EJB to get the identifier of the machine. With this, I can know which machine is processing my request.
Problem is how can I assign an ID for each machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the host name or IP of the machine itself?

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

Note: If the machines in question have multiple network interfaces, I don't think there is any guarantee which interface is returned via these methods.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's the simplest idea.
Otherwise, I also thought about generating a random number at startup using a singleton. I will try your solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a better solution that displays the pid of the process with the hostname of the machine

```
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
```

By example:
958@my-machine

Edit:
As jgitter, this is not a better solution. Just another solution. Sorry.

Comment: This of course assumes that you have JMX configured to run on your server.  "Better solution" is a stretch, it's just different.  -1 for voting for yourself.  ;-)

Comment: I didn't know that. When I found this, I just tried and worked fine.
I put your answer as solution.

Comment: No worries.  JMX is standard Java SE so virtually all containers support it, but occasionally it is disabled by default.  Cheers!